# I have this screen bug that comes and goes, is there any way to fix it?

Tags: screen, error, bug, malware

It is sort of like a static wave that goes across my screen for a second then goes away. It is rather annoying it comes once every 5 minutes i'd say.

2010 macbook pro 15" 4gb-ram NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M 512 MB Intel i7 and OSX 10.9.

What is the course of action to stop this?

Thank You

Comment: In order to determine, we would need your model, the OSX and anything else you can tell us (like a screen shot). Like does it do that if you start in Safe mode ?

Comment: 2010 macbook pro 15" 4gb-ram 
NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M 512 MB
Intel i7 and OSX 10.9

Comment: Thank you, how did it go with Safe mode (that would preclude any other app doing it). Does it do it when only on battery? does it do it when not using the NVIDIA GeForce.

Comment: Does this happen when the Macbook Pro is in another location? Does this happen when the Macbook Pro is connected to another power adaptor? Does this happen when the Macbook Pro is not connected to a power adapter at all?

Comment: It's when it's in the same location. It's an odd bug because it comes and goes. It will be fine for a day or two then intermittently it will decide to act up.

Answer (score 1):

Oddly enough that could be environmental.

In brief there could be some kind of electrical (or electromagnetic) signal that is interfering with the circuits in your Mac. It is not uncommon but usually manifests itself in something that happens all the time or only when a train (or whatever) goes by.

If it is indeed environmental (and there is no guarantee that it is) then often just re-orienting the laptop (tilt the screen at a different angle, turn the computer to face another direction, etc.) might help. Failing that moving it to another room or another location in the room that it is in.

As it is a laptop, take it outside, like to a park, far away from electrical lines and see if the issue repeats. Or try your favorite coffee shop with wifi.

If you can do any of this while the static is happening, even better as you will get immediate feedback.

Failing all of that it may be time for a visit to an Apple Genius to have them diagnose the hardware.